# Show/Hide <tr> based on MULTIPLE <select> box - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a multiple select box as follows

```
<select multiple name="transActionGroup" id="transActionGroup" ng-multiple="true" ng-model="transActionGroup" title="Hold CTRL to select more than one transaction type.">
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <option value="Custom Group">Custom Group</option>
    <option value="ACH Credits">ACH Credits</option>
    <option value="ACH Debits">ACH Debits</option>
</select>
```

I want to show a `<tr>`, which is hidden by default, when the user selects 'Custom Group' as one of his options from the above select box

This is my `<tr>`

```
<tr id="custTransGrp" ng-if="transActionGroup === 'Custom Group'">
    <td class="label-cell"> * Custom Group(s) : </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customTransActionGroup" name="customTransActionGroup" id="customTransActionGroup" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried

```
ng-if="transActionGroup === 'Custom Group'"
```

but it didn't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TahmidTanzim/N9Vqk/

Comment: If you select more than one option, transActionGroup will be an array consisting of the selected options, e.g. `['Custom Group', 'ACH Credits']`.

Comment: How can I compare this array in `ng-if` attribute?

Comment: `['Custom Group', 'ACH Credits'].indexOf('Custom Group') != -1`

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `ngModel` is an `array`, so you can't simple check with `===`.

You should use

[**`Array.prototype.indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof):

```
<tr id="custTransGrp" ng-if="transActionGroup && transActionGroup.indexOf('Custom Group') != -1">
```

or even:

[**`Array.prototype.includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (Check the browser compatibility in the link):

```
<tr id="custTransGrp" ng-if="transActionGroup.includes('Custom Group')">
```